# Retrofit Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, api, gson, retrofit

I'm using retrofit in my android app.I have a login api and it is working properly when I test it from Postman. But when I test it from my app ,it returns **Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $**
error .I've used the same api with same parameters in another activity and it is working fine there.I'm really clueless about what is going wrong.

My JSON parameters

```
{
"device_token":"device token",
"facebook_id":"1970665",
"ur_address":"342 Brooklyn Road",
"ur_category":"0",
"ur_city":"Holly Pond",
"ur_country":"US",
"ur_email":"abc@gmail.com",
"ur_gender":"female",
"ur_latitude":"34.1786998",
"ur_longitude":"-86.6154153",
"ur_name":"User name",
"ur_photo":"http://graph.facebook.com/1970665/picture?type=large",
"ur_range":"50"
}
```

My model class

```
public class LoginBody {

@SerializedName("facebook_id")
@Expose
private String facebookId;
@SerializedName("ur_name")
@Expose
private String urName;
@SerializedName("ur_email")
@Expose
private String urEmail;
@SerializedName("ur_gender")
@Expose
private String urGender;
@SerializedName("ur_photo")
@Expose
private String urPhoto;
@SerializedName("ur_range")
@Expose
private String urRange;
@SerializedName("ur_category")
@Expose
private String urCategory;
@SerializedName("ur_latitude")
@Expose
private String urLatitude;
@SerializedName("ur_longitude")
@Expose
private String urLongitude;
@SerializedName("ur_city")
@Expose
private String urCity;
@SerializedName("ur_country")
@Expose
private String urCountry;
@SerializedName("ur_address")
@Expose
private String urAddress;
@SerializedName("device_token")
@Expose
private String deviceToken;

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 *
 */
public LoginBody() {
}

/**
 *
 * @param urCategory
 * @param urCountry
 * @param deviceToken
 * @param urAddress
 * @param facebookId
 * @param urName
 * @param urCity
 * @param urEmail
 * @param urLongitude
 * @param urGender
 * @param urLatitude
 * @param urRange
 * @param urPhoto
 */
public LoginBody(String facebookId, String urName, String urEmail, String urGender, String urPhoto, String urRange, String urCategory, String urLatitude, String urLongitude, String urCity, String urCountry, String urAddress, String deviceToken) {
    super();
    this.facebookId = facebookId;
    this.urName = urName;
    this.urEmail = urEmail;
    this.urGender = urGender;
    this.urPhoto = urPhoto;
    this.urRange = urRange;
    this.urCategory = urCategory;
    this.urLatitude = urLatitude;
    this.urLongitude = urLongitude;
    this.urCity = urCity;
    this.urCountry = urCountry;
    this.urAddress = urAddress;
    this.deviceToken = deviceToken;
}

public String getFacebookId() {
    return facebookId;
}

public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
    this.facebookId = facebookId;
}

public String getUrName() {
    return urName;
}

public void setUrName(String urName) {
    this.urName = urName;
}

public String getUrEmail() {
    return urEmail;
}

public void setUrEmail(String urEmail) {
    this.urEmail = urEmail;
}

public String getUrGender() {
    return urGender;
}

public void setUrGender(String urGender) {
    this.urGender = urGender;
}

public String getUrPhoto() {
    return urPhoto;
}

public void setUrPhoto(String urPhoto) {
    this.urPhoto = urPhoto;
}

public String getUrRange() {
    return urRange;
}

public void setUrRange(String urRange) {
    this.urRange = urRange;
}

public String getUrCategory() {
    return urCategory;
}

public void setUrCategory(String urCategory) {
    this.urCategory = urCategory;
}

public String getUrLatitude() {
    return urLatitude;
}

public void setUrLatitude(String urLatitude) {
    this.urLatitude = urLatitude;
}

public String getUrLongitude() {
    return urLongitude;
}

public void setUrLongitude(String urLongitude) {
    this.urLongitude = urLongitude;
}

public String getUrCity() {
    return urCity;
}

public void setUrCity(String urCity) {
    this.urCity = urCity;
}

public String getUrCountry() {
    return urCountry;
}

public void setUrCountry(String urCountry) {
    this.urCountry = urCountry;
}

public String getUrAddress() {
    return urAddress;
}

public void setUrAddress(String urAddress) {
    this.urAddress = urAddress;
}

public String getDeviceToken() {
    return deviceToken;
}

public void setDeviceToken(String deviceToken) {
    this.deviceToken = deviceToken;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("facebookId", facebookId).append("urName", urName).append("urEmail", urEmail).append("urGender", urGender).append("urPhoto", urPhoto).append("urRange", urRange).append("urCategory", urCategory).append("urLatitude", urLatitude).append("urLongitude", urLongitude).append("urCity", urCity).append("urCountry", urCountry).append("urAddress", urAddress).append("deviceToken", deviceToken).toString();
}

}
```

Api interface

```
@POST("login")
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
Call<LoginData> loginUser(@Body LoginBody loginBody);
```

Postman response

```
{
"status": 1,
"message": "success",
"user": {
    "ur_id": "4",
    "facebook_id": "1970665",
    "ur_name": "User name",
    "ur_email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "ur_latitude": "34.1786998",
    "ur_longitude": "-86.6154153",
    "ur_city": "Holly Pond",
    "ur_country": "US",
    "ur_gender": "0",
    "ur_range": "494",
    "ur_sub_status": "0",
    "created_at": "2017-12-01 18:15:41",
    "ur_address": "342 Brooklyn Road",
    "ur_photo": "http://graph.facebook.com/1970665/picture?type=large",
    "ur_device_token": "device token"
}
}
```

Comment: Post your response. You are making mistake in parsing of your response.

Comment: In response,I get the error

Comment: put your postman response, so we can get ideas that where you getting problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please put the response, Here he says " I was expecting some value in the response to be an Object but I found a String ".

For example expected:

```
"key" : {
        "inner_key" : "value"
        }
```

And found:

```
"key" : "value"
```